# Do aliases slow down a shell's start?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, zsh, alias

Sometimes my shell (zsh) takes longer to start than usual (I open the terminal, and it hangs a bit until I can input commands).

I have a few aliases on my *.zshrc* (well, actually they're in a different file that *.zshrc* does a `source` on).

If you make an `alias` with the shell open, it remains valid only through the current session, so I started to wonder if all this `source` and `alias` actually harm the shell's startup performance (I'm assuming it has to go through a lengthy process of running all those commands on start).

If that does happen, wouldn't it just be more effective to have those aliases as shell scripts and put them somewhere in my *PATH*?

Comment: I'm fairly sure aliases don't significantly contribute to shell startup times. Initializing modules such as completion, or sourcing other files such as oh-my-zsh might have a much higher impact. Have you done some experiments on how your performance is when you disable the aliases?

Comment: I'd rather suspect an illegal amount of completions. Show the output of `set | wc`. Or some dns lookup may happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's unlikely that having a few extra alias definitions in your startup files are responsible for noticeable startup delays.  Even if you had so many it actually mattered, the delay wouldn't be sporadic, it'd be the same every time.

What's more likely is that something along the way in your startup sequence is waiting for the network.  An example would be a path directory that's on a network drive that isn't ready or perhaps isn't powered up at all.  Network timeouts are often many seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are NOT doing a 'dump' of your completion system when calling compinit? (that could slow down zsh at start up...). If you are using compinit, make sure you are just calling

```
autoload -U compinit
compinit
```

(without any funny options for compinit, specifically without `-D`).

After using that, the first time you start a shell it will be slow (as it will generate the dump, but the next ones will not).

Other thoughts, perhaps your system messes with the completion functions, and a new dump is forcefully generated each time? Try setting compinit in your `.zshrc` with `-C` (after generating the dump at least once).

Answer (score 0):

For those who use oh-my-zsh it worth to know that it sets a different name to the .zcompudump file, it is: $ZSH_COMPDUMP.
The idea is to test if the file is older than one day and regenatates it.
My attempt, please guys comment to give me some advises about it:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
if [[ -n ${ZDOTDIR:-${HOME}}/$ZSH_COMPDUMP(#qN.mh+24) ]]; then
    compinit -d $ZSH_COMPDUMP;
else
    compinit -C;
fi;

# -D ........... disables .zcompudump file
# -d ........... used to set an alternative name to .zcompdump
# -i ........... accept insecure files
# -C ........... ignore checking at all
```

References:

- https://gist.github.com/ctechols/ca1035271ad134841284
- https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/778271/Speed-up-zsh-compinit-by-only-checking-c