# alias slowed down zsh

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I've added an alias and slowed down my zsh opening time. It opens but just hangs for extra 1 or 2 seconds to give me a prompt (or it starts typing my command without prompt before it, at the top of the shell)

There is an another question about it, but it resulted in that slowing down is not about aliases.

[Do aliases slow down a shell's start?](https://superuser.com/questions/543649/do-aliases-slow-down-a-shells-start)

I have an alias, which helps me start the android emulator based on the name one of the avd names from the list, wait 2 seconds, and then run flutter.

```
alias runflutter="emulator @$(avdmanager list avd | grep -m 1 -Po '(?<=Name:\s).*'  ) &; sleep 2;  flutter run"
```

Main reason that I'm sure that my problem is about that alias is, when I test with `/usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit`
Gives me this:

```
2.27user 0.18system 0:01.07elapsed 228%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 141092maxresident)k
0inputs+112outputs (0major+50607minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

If delete my alias the output of the same command

```
0.24user 0.11system 0:00.35elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 16036maxresident)k
0inputs+96outputs (0major+16089minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

**What are my thoughts and done so far**

I thought that I've already flutter command, so maybe having an alias with the flutter keyword on it cause some indexing problems, not sure if indexing or something similar exists. So I have renamed my alias, nothing changed.

My other theory is, since there is almost 2 second delay and 2.0 difference between the numbers before the 'user' in the output, I thought it might be about my sleep command in the alias. It's executed somehow. I've deleted sleep command from my alias but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> alias runflutter="emulator @**$(avdmanager list avd | grep -m 1 -Po '(?<=Name:\s).*' )** &; sleep 2;  flutter run"

The bold part of this alias is being executed when you define the alias. Is that behavior you want? How long does that take to run?

It's my gut feeling that you're sleeping for 2 seconds because you wanted to give avdmanager time to run.  If so, you might like the results of

```
setopt rcquotes
alias runflutter='emulator @$(avdmanager list avd | grep -m 1 -Po ''(?<=Name:\s).*'' ) &; sleep 2; flutter run'
setopt norcquotes
```

better.

I would, in general, recommend the use of rcquotes, and not turning it off otherwise, because without rcquotes, the shortest way I know to quote a single quote in a single quoted string is an unwieldy `'\''`. If you prefer, you could do that instead of the rcquotes thing, giving you

```
alias runflutter='emulator @$(avdmanager list avd | grep -m 1 -Po '\''(?<=Name:\s).*'\'' ) &; sleep 2; flutter run'
```

Comment: That works and I'm satisfied with the results. Thank you so much! I've also test the  `/usr/bin/time zsh -i -c exit` and results seem normal. And yes, with `sleep`, I want to give emulator time to set up before run the project with flutter run. However, I didn't understand why the bold part start being executed when I define it.

Comment: When you use double quotes in zsh, bash, or ksh, $() gets evaluated immediately.  I think there's other shells in that list, but I don't know for certain off the top of my head.